# How to ignore texts that have specific html tags in XPath Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[*] I want to extract just the valid users from link below:
http://ashiyane.org/forums/memberlist.php?page=100&pp=100&order=desc&sort=posts

Above link is contains valid and invalid/banned users.
invalid/banned users are marked with the `<strike> </strike>` pattern.

[*] I want to ignore and extract just the valid users like as "varzandeh121".
"varzandeh121" is a valid user in site.
"momo55" is invalid/banned user in site.

[*] Script below extracts all users (valid and invalid):

```
driver.get("http://ashiyane.org/forums/memberlist.php?page=100&pp=100&order=desc&sort=posts")  
users = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[@class='alt1 username']/a[contains(@class,'username')]")  

for ss in users:  
        print "All Users :( ", ss.text
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banned users have tag `strike`. You need to amend your xpath expression: add xpath [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/not) function and select users without that tag.

```
  users = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='username' and not(strike)]")
```

Comment: Hi dear @Vold. Thanks a lot :X